# In biblatex, treat periods in journal as abbreviation dots

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I would like to consistently have a comma between the journal and volume number for article references using `biblatex` with `biber` as the backend. Unfortunately, the punctuation between the journal and volume is not consistent. Journals whose last word is abbreviated have no comma between the journal and the volume, and the word "Vol." is capitalized. Journals whose last word is not abbreviated have a comma and the word "vol." is not capitalized. I can fix the capitalization by un-commenting the commented lines in the below MWE, but the comma problem is quite perplexing. Apologies if this fix is in an answer somewhere, but I cannot find it (or at least, I don't know what to search for!).

Current output:
[1] First Author. “Blah Blah 2”. In: *Am. J. Phys.* Vol. 72, no. 3 (Mar. 2004),
pp. 367–375.
[2] Second Author. “Blah blah”. In: *Energy Fuel*, vol. 27, no. 12 (Dec. 2013),
pp. 7778–7789.

Expected output:
[1] First Author. “Blah Blah 2”. In: *Am. J. Phys.*, vol. 72, no. 3 (Mar. 2004),
pp. 367–375.
[2] Second Author. “Blah blah”. In: *Energy Fuel*, vol. 27, no. 12 (Dec. 2013),
pp. 7778–7789.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
% \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    % volume = {\lowercase{v}ol\adddot}, % avoid capitalization after dots.
% }
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}\addspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addspace #1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%<---- was \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{York2004,
author = {Author, First},
journal = {Am. J. Phys.},
month = mar,
number = {3},
pages = {367--375},
title = {{Blah Blah 2}},
volume = {72},
year = {2004}
}
@article{Baumgardner2013a,
author = {Author, Second},
journal = {Energy Fuel},
month = dec,
number = {12},
pages = {7778--7789},
title = {{Blah blah}},
volume = {27},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is because the `journal` in `York2004` ends with a `.` dot. The dot is then treated as such to avoid double punctuation.

Comment: Yes, but it is an abbreviation, not the end of a sentence. I *want* the double punctuation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `biblatex` treats the abbreviation dot in `journal = {Am. J. Phys.}` as a literal period (the end of a sentence).

We can stop `biblatex` from doing that by using `\isdot`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
```

As per the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) §4.7.3 *Adding Punctuation*, p. 191:

> `\isdot` Turns a previously inserted literal period into an
>   abbreviation dot. In contrast to `\adddot`, nothing is inserted if
>   this command is not preceded by a period.

This solution will treat all trailing periods in the `journal` field as abbreviation dots.

If you only want that for particular cases, you could consider adding `\isdot` to the `journal` field manually (`journal = {Am. J. Phys.\isdot}` or write `journal = {Am\adddotspace J\adddotspace Phys\adddot}` using the host of commands `biblatex` provides for these matters). This is is not to be recommended as it will make the `.bib` file less portable though.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}\addspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addspace #1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%<---- was \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{York2004,
author = {Author, First},
journal = {Am. J. Phys.},
month = mar,
number = {3},
pages = {367--375},
title = {{Blah Blah 2}},
volume = {72},
year = {2004}
}
@article{Baumgardner2013a,
author = {Author, Second},
journal = {Energy Fuel},
month = dec,
number = {12},
pages = {7778--7789},
title = {{Blah blah}},
volume = {27},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail! I should probably just read the biblatex docs all the way through... maybe after I graduate :-)

Comment: @darthbith That will surely be a very gripping read `;-)`.