# Historische Zeitschrift Style capitalizing first letter problem

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I am using Historische Zeitschrift Style and the probem I have is that it capitalises some of the things it shouldn't. Let me try to explain.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1998,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {Athanasius Werke - Die dogmatischen Schriften},
    Call-Number = {TH: Vb 17.02-1.1.2},
    Date-Added = {2010-10-16 13:24:30 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-13 17:12:32 +0000},
    Editor = {Marin Tetz and others},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {109-175},
    Publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
    Read = {No},
    Series = {Urkunden zur Geschichte des Arianischen Streites 318-328},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {Ar. 1},
    Title = {Oratio I contra Arianos},
    Volume = {1, Tl. 1, Lfg. 2},
    Year = {1998}}
@incollection{evagrius2011,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Evagrius Scholasticus}},
    Booktitle = {{\'E}vagre Le Scholastique: Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique - Livres I-III},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va1.05/542},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-24 12:11:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:31 +0000},
    Editor = {Joseph Bidez and Leon Parmentier},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {Evagr.},
    Shorttitle = {h.e.},
    Title = {Historia ecclesiastica},
    Volume = {542},
    Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
       {\iffieldundef{usera}
         {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}}{\printnames{author}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{title}\isdot%
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \usebibmacro{in:}%
          \printfield{usera}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \printfield[default]{volume}}}}
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{evagrius2011}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 11]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{evagrius2011}
\end{document}
```

When I compile that this is what I get:

[image]

The letter "W" (marked with the red arrow) should here be small but because `Shorttitle` of that entry has a dot at the end (h.e.) it capitalises the first letter in the brackets.

If you compare it with the previous entry (Ar. 1) you will notice that that one doesn't have capital "W".

So how do I make it stop capitalising "W"? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You probably need to add an `\isdot` after abbreviations such as "h.e." that end with a dot. See also the related [In biblatex, treat periods in journal as abbreviation dots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170547/35864), which can be applied to all kinds of fields, not just `journal`, but also `shorttitle`.

Comment: Ok thank you for this. It works and I tried making this permanent instead of adding \isdot in every entry. For that purpose I tried to renew \renewbibmacro*{footcite:note} and add there \isdot before \bibleftparen. This doesn't work but if I go to the file historische-zeitschrift.cbx and replace it there it works. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened there, I would probably have to see the code, it should work in a document as well. I would, however, just try `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\isdot}`.

Comment: Actually that worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: OK, I voted to close your question as a duplicate of the question I linked to above.