# Biblatex: delimiter between type and school

Tags: biblatex

My document (LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits=true,sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=3]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{schmidt14}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The file "lit.bib":

```
@phdthesis{schmidt14,
  author = {Schmidt, Johannes},
  title = {Testtest},
  school = {Test Univ.},
  year = {2014},
}
```

But there is no comma between "Diss." (German abbreviation for a PhD thesis) and the school:

[image]

What can I do? How can I modify the default style? Other styles put a comma there.

(btw, the 
    `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`
doesn't matter, same problem with English. I included it nonetheless for the minimal example. The document is written in German.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you are interested in german help, you should check out [TeXwelt](http://www.texwelt.de).

Comment: A lot of different `bib` styles are available. Have you gone through them yet? http://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/bibstyles.pdf

Comment: Does this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170547/in-biblatex-treat-periods-in-journal-as-abbreviation-dots help?

Comment: Biblatex not bibtex. Also I don't want to use another style. I just want to know the command like `\nametitledelim` for type and school.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `type` field is not printed within a macro but in the driver directly, so we will have to modify the `@thesis` driver.
We can do this quite neatly with the [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package.

```
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\printfield{type}%
   \newunit}
  {\printfield{type}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {}{}
```

We simply add an explicit `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` after the type field instead of the normal `\newunit`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits=true,sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=3]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{schmidt14,
  author = {Schmidt, Johannes},
  title = {Testtest},
  school = {Test Univ.},
  year = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\printfield{type}%
   \newunit}
  {\printfield{type}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {}{}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  \cite{schmidt14}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! There is sadly still one problem: It doesn't work if the "type" field in the .bib-file is used.

Comment: @user3629500 It should work in that case as well, but if your `type` fields ends in a period, you will have to add `\isdot` just after that dot, like `type = {PhD diss.\isdot}`. We could circumvent this by adding `\DeclareFieldFormat{type}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}\isdot}` to the preamble. (See [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170547/35864)).

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}{%
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
}
{%
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
}{}{}
```

[image]