# biblatex - How can I force a colon after a period?

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to print a colon after a period, i.e. after *Hrsg.* (German version of *eds.*). How can I achieve to have a colon after the string for `{editors}`?

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
12pt,
ngerman
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
language=german,
style=authoryear-ibid,
backend=biber,
hyperref=true,
dashed=false,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
uniquename=init,
uniquelist=false,
autocite=footnote,
ibidtracker=true,
date=comp,
mincrossrefs=1,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
    byeditor = {Hrsg.},%
    byeditor = {Hrsg.},%
    andothers={et \addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
        \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
        \newunit%
        \clearname{editor}%
        \newunit}
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{abc,
Title                    = {Stuff},
Author                   = {Lamp, Jones},
Date                     = {2011},
Crossref ={ddd}
}
@collection{ddd,
    Title= {Words},
    Editor={Smith, John and Doe, Jane},
    Date={2012},
    Location={Towntown}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
Words.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just go with `byeditor = {Hrsg\adddot}` instead of `byeditor = {Hrsg.}` (see [In biblatex, treat periods in journal as abbreviation dots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170547/35864) for example). `biblatex` by default thinks a "." is a full stop and suppresses following punctuation to avoid double punctuation, if an "." is actually an abbreviation dot, you need to tell `biblatex`, either by issuing `.\isdot`, or by using the appropriate `\adddot` command.

Comment: @moewe That worked. Please provide your comment as a reply so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That behaviour is due to `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker. `biblatex` tries - with all its might - to avoid double punctuation like ".," or ":." and the like.

The "." character can have to different "meanings", it can be (1) a *full stop* signalling the end of a sentence, or (2) it can be an *abbreviation dot* indicating an abbreviation.
By default, `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker will treat any "." it encounters as full stops (i.e. sentence endings).
Obviously it is not desirable to have a colon directly after a full stop.

But here, in "Hrsg.", the "." is an abbreviation dot, and as such (and unlike the full stop) has no particular aversion to being followed by a colon or a comma.

So all we need to do is to convince `biblatex` that the "." in "Hrsg." is a dot.
This can be done by the `\isdot` command (see [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) §4.7.3 *Adding Punctuation*, p. 199)

> `\isdot` Turns a previously inserted literal period into an
>   abbreviation dot. In contrast to `\adddot`, nothing is inserted if
>   this command is not preceded by a period.

So that would be `byeditor = {Hrsg.\isdot}` then.

In this particular case, however, (especially when defining bibstrings) `\adddot` is more appropriate (see p. 198 of the previously mentioned section in the [doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf))

> `\adddot` Adds a period unless it is preceded by any punctuation mark.
>   The purpose of this command is inserting the dot after an
>   abbreviation. Any dot inserted this way is recognized as such by the
>   other punctuation commands. This command may also be used to turn a
>   previously inserted literal period into an abbreviation dot.

So we just write

```
byeditor = {Hrsg\adddot}
```