# Adding comma after journal name in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In the following code how can I add a comma after the journal name without changing the style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mynum-compbib.bib}
@article{goss1981simple,
author = "David Goss",
title = "A simple approach to the analytic continuation and values at the negative integers for the Riemann zeta function",
journal= "Proc. Am. Math. Soc.",
volume = "81",
number = "4",
pages = "513-517",
year = 1981,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mynum-compbib.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
\iffieldundef{number}{}{%
\printtext{no\adddot\addspace}%
}%
\printfield{number}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{eid}}
\begin{document}
\cite{goss1981simple}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Currently what I get is:

> D. Goss. A simple approach to the analytic continuation and values at
>   the negative integers for the Riemann zeta function, *Proc. Am. Math.
>   Soc.* **81**, no. 4 (1981), 513-517.

What I want is:

> D. Goss. A simple approach to the analytic continuation and values at
>   the negative integers for the Riemann zeta function, *Proc. Am. Math.
>   Soc.*, **81**, no. 4 (1981), 513-517.

Note the comma after Soc. is what I want.

Secondly how can I change the full stop after the author name into a comma?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you write `journal= "Proc. Am. Math. Soc.,",` ?

Comment: @juanuni: Of course, that will work. But that is not how I have built my collection of bibliographies (there are a large number of references) and I want a way to automatically have a comma.

Comment: For your second problem try `\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}` or more radical (check if you like it!) `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We will need to do two changes.

First we need to tell `biblatex` that dots in the `journaltitle` fields are by no means full stops, but abbreviation dots. This can be done by adding `\isdot` after the field formatting directive.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}
```

See [In biblatex, treat periods in journal as abbreviation dots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170547/35864) and  [biblatex - How can I force a colon after a period?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200332/35864) for a more thorough explanation and investigation of this problem.

We then need to tell `biblatex` to print a comma after the journal name, and this can be done via

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
```

Where in the third line we have swapped `\setunit*{\addspace}%` for `\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{goss1981simple,
author = "David Goss",
title = "A simple approach to the analytic continuation and values at the negative integers for the Riemann zeta function",
journal= "Proc. Am. Math. Soc.",
volume = "81",
number = "4",
pages = "513-517",
year = 1981,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{number}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \printfield{eid}}
\begin{document}
\cite{goss1981simple}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]