# Referencing style in Lyx

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

Journal example:

> Gray, Jo Anna. (1976). "Wage Indexation-A Macroeconomic Approach." Journal of Monetary Economics 2, 221-235.

Book example

> Blanchard, Olivier J., and Stanley Fischer. (1989). Lectures on Macroeconomics. Cambridge, MA.: MIT Press.

Can anyone please suggest me, which style in Lyx can produce this type of referencing style. Its the style of Journal of Money, Credit and Banking. It looks like, all names appear in full and second author's name style is different than the first author's. I tried several options while adding my .bib file to main Lyx file, but couldn't produce this. Style jmr in Lyx produces close but not exactly same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is some kind of author-year style you want. If you use `biblatex`, it will be easier to customise, starting from this basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bernard commented, you may use BibLaTeX.

For the use of BibLaTeX with LyX see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314996/101651).

I've taken an article from the journal you cited to see which part of the reference should be in italic, unfortunately I haven't found books cited in that article, so I've based my answer only on your question for that.

This is the `.bib` file (since you didn't post yours, I've taken the citation from Google Scholar exporting them in BibTeX with little changes):

```
@article{gray1976wage,
    title={Wage indexation: a macroeconomic approach.},
    author={Gray, Jo Anna},
    journal={Journal of Monetary Economics},
    volume={2},
    pages={221--235},
    year={1976},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@book{blanchard1989lectures,
    title={Lectures on macroeconomics},
    author={Blanchard, Olivier J. and Fischer, Stanley},
    year={1989},
    publisher={MIT press},
    address={Cambridge, MA.}
}
```

This is the code (you have to put the lines between the two `%---` in your  LaTeX Preamble under the LyX menu option Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble):

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%---
% BibLaTeX
\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Dot after author
\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\setunit{\addperiod\space}}{}{}

% No in: before journal title
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 

% Comma after journal title
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}

% Non-italic book title (if it must be in italic, comment this line)
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}

% No pp. before pages
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1} 

% Add bibliography database
\addbibresource{your-bib-file.bib}
%---

\begin{document}

    Article:\\
    Citation of the type Author (year): \citet{gray1976wage} \\
    Citation of the type (Author, year): \citep{gray1976wage}

    Book:\\
    Citation of the type Author (year): \citet{blanchard1989lectures} \\
    Citation of the type (Author, year): \citep{blanchard1989lectures}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The code for the dot after the author is taken from the comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83987/101651).

The code for the comma after the journal title comes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249025/101651).

The rest more or less could be found in the link of Elad Den's answer.

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Sadia You are welcome! If my answer has met your needs, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark, in that way your question won't appear in the UNanswered list (but it will remain in the general one) and we both will earn reputation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

how about the `apalike` style  ?

in any case, you can customize your bibliography as Bernard said.
check out this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/90297)

Comment: Doesn't `apalike` truncate given names to the first initials?