# Biblatex ibid in lowercase if prenote is present

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, xstring, xpatch

I've defined my own biblatex style (see MWE) which uses citations in footnotes.
I've patched the `prenote` command, because otherwise biblatex writes the prenote text in lowercase (note: I don't want to write the prenote in uppercase within the autocite command, because I want to be able to switch back to in text citation).

But now I have a problem with the third citation where the abbreviated `cf.` is used. The following ibid should be printed in lowercase letters just like in the second citation (before the patching the ibid was written in lowercase but also the cf.).
If no prenote is present the ibid should be printed like the fourth citation.

How can I achieve the desired behavior and maybe get rid of the patching, because it is a bit slow.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote,backend=biber,ibidtracker=constrict]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@BOOK{ABC,
    author = {Cornelisse, J. W. and Schöyer, H. Ferry R. and Wakker, Karel F.},
    title = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics},
    year = {1979},
    publisher = {Pitman},
}
\end{filecontents*}

 \providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
 \newbool{cbx:loccit}

 \DeclareBibliographyOption{ibidpage}[true]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
     {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=constrict}}
     {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=false}}}

 \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{ibidpage = true}

 \newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
    \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
    \ifloccit
     {\global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
     {}}

     \newbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
     \ifbool{cbx:loccit}
        {}
        {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}

    \newbibmacro*{cite:prenote}{%
     \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
        {\usebibmacro{prenote}}}

 \DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{cite:prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
     {\printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}\usebibmacro{postnote}}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

     \DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}

     \DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}{\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstchar]\StrLen{#1}[\textlaenge]\StrMid{#1}{2}{\textlaenge}[\restchars]\autocap{\firstchar}\restchars}
     \xpatchbibmacro{prenote}{\printfield{prenote}}{\printfield[sentencecase]{prenote}}{}{}
     \xpatchbibmacro{multiprenote}{\printfield{multiprenote}}{\printfield[sentencecase]{multiprenote}}{}{}

\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
     Work\autocite[see][20]{ABC}.\\
     Same work with a prenote without a punctation\autocite[see][20]{ABC}.\\
     Same work with a prenote with punctation\autocite[cf.][20]{ABC}.\\
     Same work and no prenote\autocite[][20]{ABC}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @moewe Thank you, but then I have to change all my previously written citations. I wonder why biblatex does the right thing before the patching where the ibid was printed in lowercase letters. So before the patching it was obvious for biblatex that the dot is just an abbreviation dot.

Comment: Use `\autocite[cf.\isdot][20]{ABC}`. You have to tell `biblatex` that the `.` in the prenote is not a full stop (sentence ending), but an abbreviation dot in this instance, as `biblatex` will automatically capitalise after the former, but not after a `.` of the latter kind. (See also [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170547/35864))

Comment: The standard behaviour for `prenote` is `\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{#1\isdot}` (i.e. `biblatex` assumes a `.` is an abbreviation dot, never a sentence ending), but after your patching, you print the `prenote` with `\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}`, whose definition does not have the `\isdot` in it. If you add the `\isdot` to the end of the `\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}` bit (after `\restchars`) it seems to work again.

Comment: By the way: you could just go with `\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstchar]\StrLen{#1}[\textlaenge]\StrMid{#1}{2}{\textlaenge}[\restchars]\autocap{\firstchar}\restchars\isdot}` and there would be no need for the patching (which I don't think is the performance issue here, I would be more sceptical of the whole string manipulation bit).

Comment: @moewe The way without the patch and direct definition of prenote isn't working. I got 18 errors. Must of them stating `Missing number, treated as zero`. But the thing with `\isdot` works perfect.

Comment: Hmmm, it seemed to work here with the MWE above. But is really hard to say what went wrong, but I guess, if the other way works for you that's fine. When I copy-and-pasted the code I suggested above, I got that error, too; but the code in my document (where it works) seems to look exactly the same - odd (no idea why that happens). You could change you `\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}` declaration by making it a `\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}` and adding a `\isdot` before the last curly brace - that's what I did, which seems to work.

Comment: @moewe Really strange, but it works. Thanks again :)

Comment: @moewe Seems you solved the mystery once more in a comment. Wanna answer? :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Done. I finally got around to write something down. Better late than never, I assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard definition of the `prenote` field format is `\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{#1\isdot}` so that any `.` in the prenote is treated as an abbreviation dot (after which we don't start a new sentence, and thus do not capitalise). But when you define `sentencecase` there is no `\isdot`, so every `.` is treated as a full stop after which we capitalise.

We can use the following definition

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{%
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstchar]%
  \StrLen{#1}[\textlaenge]%
  \StrMid{#1}{2}{\textlaenge}[\restchars]%
  \autocap{\firstchar}\restchars\isdot}
\DeclareFieldAlias{multiprenote}{prenote}
```

then there is no need to use `xpatch` to patch into the `prenote` macro because we change the field format directly.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote,backend=biber,ibidtracker=constrict]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xstring}


 \providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
 \newbool{cbx:loccit}

 \DeclareBibliographyOption{ibidpage}[true]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
     {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=constrict}}
     {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=false}}}

 \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{ibidpage = true}

 \newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
    \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
    \ifloccit
     {\global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
     {}}

     \newbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
     \ifbool{cbx:loccit}
        {}
        {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}

    \newbibmacro*{cite:prenote}{%
     \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
        {\usebibmacro{prenote}}}

 \DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{cite:prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
     {\printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}\usebibmacro{postnote}}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}

\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{%
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstchar]%
  \StrLen{#1}[\textlaenge]%
  \StrMid{#1}{2}{\textlaenge}[\restchars]%
  \autocap{\firstchar}\restchars\isdot}
\DeclareFieldAlias{multiprenote}{prenote}


\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
     Work\autocite[see][20]{sigfridsson}.\\
     Same work with a prenote without a punctation\autocite[see][20]{sigfridsson}.\\
     Same work with a prenote with punctation\autocite[cf.][20]{sigfridsson}.\\
     Same work and no prenote\autocite[][20]{sigfridsson}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better late than never, i fully agree. :-)